# Php adding mysql from 2 tables data

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a problem retrieving some data from 2 tables and then displaying the output into one area.

This is the code for the retrieve I have

```
$select_users = "SELECT CarID, Model, Year, Price, ManuName  FROM Vehicle, Manufacturer";
        //run query

        $result = mysql_query($select_users);
```

This is the code for the output

```
<?php
while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$user_row = sprintf(
"<li><a href='select_veh.php?CarID=%d' class='mainnavstyle'>%s %s %s %s</a></li>", 
    $user['CarID'], 
    $user['ManuName'], 
    $user['Model'], 
    $user['Year'], 
    $user['Price']);
                echo $user_row;

           }
    ?>
```

I cant seem to get 'ManuName' to show properly as its from a different table.
At the moment with this code im getting duplicate results:

```
honda Civic 2000 $15,000

honda Corolla 1991 $5,000

Toyota Civic 2000 $15,000

Toyota Corolla 1991 $5,000
```

Instead of just

```
Honda Civic 2000 $15,000
Toyota Corolla 1991 $5,000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
thanks

Comment: It is better to usr join query between two table

Answer (score 3):

You are performing a cross join, which matches every row of one table, with every row of the other. This is almost certainly what you don't want. You instead need to limit how the tables join together, to do this, your tables Vehicle and Manufacturer need to be related to each other, as such:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
   id integer primary key auto_increment,
   name varchar(255)
  );

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  year integer,
  price double,
  manufacturer_id integer not null,
  FOREIGN KEY(manufacturer_id) REFERENCES manufacturer(id)
);
```

You can then get the information you want like this:

```
SELECT m.name, v.name, v.year, v.price FROM vehicle v
    INNER JOIN manufacturer m
    ON v.manufacturer_id = m.id
```

You can see this in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c1f2/1

Answer (score 0):

In `vehicle` table I would have the foreign key of manufacturer, and than query would be something like:

`SELECT Vehicle.CarID, Vehicle.Model, Vehicle.Year, Vehicle.Price, Vehicle.ManuName, Manufacturer.name
INNER JOIN Manufacturer ON(Vehicle.manufacturerId = Manufacturer.id)
FROM Vehicle`

Answer (score 0):

you could do the sql query together, using unions or joins

alternatively, this is what you can do too:

```
$sql1= "SELECT something FROM tbl WHERE column='".query."'";
$result1= $con->query($sql1);
if($result1->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {     
        $rowans = $row["row"];

        $sql2= "SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE column2= '".something."'"; 
        $gettingRows2= $con->query($sql);
        if($gettingRows2->num_rows > 0){
            while($anotherrow= $sql2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $sql2Row= $anotherrow["row2"];
            }   
        }
    }
}
        echo $rowans." ".$sql2Row;
```